# Error in Webview with targetSdkVersion 24

Tags: android, iframe, webview, android-webview

My app has a `WebView` which loads a simple HTML page with an iFrame that is used for loading an URL for payment process from a partner company (and I have no access to that url source).

When I point the `targetSdkVersion` to 19 everything works fine and I can make payments through the iFrame. However, when the `targetSdkVersion` is pointed to 24 I don't have the same luck.

In that case, the `WebView` manages to load the iFrame which is shown some `EditText` for entering with credit card information and a `Button` to submit it, but I always have an error 500 when I click on that button.

Since the payment URL is outsourced, I reached our partner company to get to know the origem from the 500 error. And they told me the error comes from a double call which makes me think something in the `WebView`from api 24 is doing so.

The 500 error's print:
[image]

The `HTML` file `payment_html` is the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    </head>

    <body id="bodyContent" onload="addListener()" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden;height:355px">
        <iframe id="ifrPagamento" src="partner_url"
            frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function addListener() {
            window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
        }

        function receiveMessage(message) {

            if (message) {

                var data = JSON.parse(message.data);

                if (data.code) {

                    if(data.code === "0") {
                        app.returnStatus(0);
                    }
                    else {
                        app.returnStatus(1);
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    </script>
</html>
```

The `partner_url` is replaced by the partner company's URL and I get it dynamically as bellow:

```
private void loadPage() {

    String url = (String) Session.getObject(Session.Key.PARTNER_URL, "");

    InputStream inputStream = mActivity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.payment_html);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {

        int i = inputStream.read();

        while (i != -1) {

            byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            i = inputStream.read();

        }

        inputStream.close();

        String html = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
        html = html.replace("partner_url", url);

        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

    } catch (IOException e) {

        Funcoes.printError(e.getMessage());

    }

}
```

I set the `WebView` up like the following:

```
private void setupWebView() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(mActivity), "app");

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            return true;
        }

    });

}
```

And finally the `layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">

    </WebView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As I said before, I don't have the url's source because it's outsource. So I can't share it.

I've been struggling with this issue for a couple of weeks. Can anyone help me?

Comment: remove this line and check in api 24 , if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }

Comment: It isn't that. That line is just to allow debugging through browser and works only for KITKAT and higher.

Comment: Is it working in api 23?

Comment: @PravinD No. It works only until api 20, which is kitkat. From api 21 it no longer works.

Comment: Try overriding only shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url), I know its deprecated but just want you to try it.

Comment: Is above solution works?

Comment: @PravinD If you take a look at my code you'll see I did it already. I overrode 2 methods, one for previous to kitkat and another later to it.

Comment: I am talking about to override only deprecated one, remove new method that introduced in API 24, just for checking whether this is the issue or not.

Comment: @PravinD I've done it before. I tried only one and then the other but no success :(

Comment: Please, show us class `MyJavaScriptInterface`

Comment: @OleksiiKropachov That class is just for catching a javascript call. And I've already tried to take it off, but didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few weeks, I found out this https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#BehaviorWebView which explains the changes of api 21. Take a look at the `WebView` part that says:

**If your application works with API level 21 or later:**

- The system locks mixed content and third-party cookies by default. To
  allow mixed content and third-party cookies, use the methods
  setMixedContentMode()and setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(), respectively.

So, I only added these configurations into `WebView`and it worked perfectly.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

    webSettings.setMixedContentMode(MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true);

}
```

Comment: Yup was going to answer Android has upgraded its security policies but found your answer which was precisely my point.